# How to handle the click event of all one type of objects in single place in vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-applications

I have many image buttons on my page based on asp.net, I want to handle the click event of all in a single sub.. 
The reason for this is; the number of image buttons can increase or decrease by programming...
So i want something like this...

```
Private sub , (this sub must handle all the image buttons on the page)

My code come here

End sub
```

Now user clicks whichever image button, this sub should be fire.

Comment: A little more info would help.  1.)  How do the image buttons get onto the page, do you manually put them there or are they dynamically added?  2.) If they're dynamically added, what is the mechanism, are you using a repeater, adding them to the form collection manually, etc?  You maybe able to change your design pattern slightly and accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 0):

One `Private Sub` handles multiple `image button`

```
   Private Sub imagebtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles imagbtn1.Click, imagbtn2.Click, imagbtn3.Click, imagbtn4.Click, and so on
        'code here
   End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks rhidzzz. But imagebutton1 or 2 or 3 are not specific... these may b in hundreds... so its not possible for me to do so..

Comment: Please mark this as a solution if it works on your need.